# checkbox management in react-markdown

Tags: javascript

I have a simple component structure

```
    import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
    import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';


    const App = () => {
      const testDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

      const md = `
     - [ ] todo
     - [x] done
             `;

      return (
        <div className="App" ref={testDivRef}>
          <ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}>
            {md}
          </ReactMarkdown>
        </div>
      );
     };
```

There is a problem, checkboxes are rendered with the disabled attribute and there is no way to control it.

Can anyone suggest maybe there are standard solutions to this problem, how it can be managed?

I tried to access these elements through markup, and manage them piece by piece, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
      useEffect(() => {
         if (testDivRef.current) {
         const handleCheckboxClick = (event: Event) => {
         console.log(event);
         const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
         target.checked = !target.checked;
       };

      const checkboxes = testDivRef.current.querySelectorAll(
        'input[type="checkbox"]'
      );
      checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.removeAttribute('disabled');
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', handleCheckboxClick);
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

The disabled atbirut is removed, the object arrives in the event, but the value of the input itself does not change.

Comment: same quesiton dude

Comment: You still haven't found a solution? :(